# redirect ALL trafic including JS/CSS to https

Tags: .htaccess

I have https installed but websites uses ABOSLUTE http:// links

I tried to solve that with .htaccess such as:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

But still images and JS are fetched from http and not from https which gives me errors.

How can I force ALL to be fetched by HTTPS ? (including JS and Images) using .htaccess

Comment: The only way to really "solve" the problem is to change your `http://...` absolute URLs to `https://...` (or `//...` - protocol relative).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will take any http request made to your site and 301 redirect it to the https equivalent:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

Comment: SAME: JS and CSS are still fetched from http and not from https

Comment: Well that's odd - what happens when you open a CSS / JS resource in your browser directly? It should 301 them unless there's something else interfering...

Comment: @yarek: After this rule in place try clearing your browser cache completely.